# Multi Site Multi Domain

Tags: multi-site, redirect, multi-environment, multi-domain

Probably this one is repeated, but I couldn't find an answer for it yet.

I have a multi-site in Craft CMS 3.15, one that is in English and another one in Japanese.

So the English page, which is the default, is `www.mysite.com`, and my other site, is working fine if the domain is `www.mysite.com/jp`

However, I want to change the domain for the Japanese site to be `www.myjapanesesite.com/home` and is not working as I expected as the browser says that there have been too many redirects.

How can I make this possible on Craft? Is there anything else I should config in Craft or in the `htaccess` file?

The redirects section from my `htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteRule ^(autodiscover) - [L]
   
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mysite.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

While the `Base URL` for my English site is `https://www.mysite.com` and the Japanese one is `https://www.mysite.com/jp` (I have tried to change it to `www.myjapanesesite.com/home` but that's when it doesn't work).

Thanks in advance

Note: I have set the alias for this site [www.myjapanesesite.com](http://www.myjapanesesite.com) in SiteHost (the hosting service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* you need to use tweak the `config/general.php` file in order to have a baseUrl for a site that is a different domain name.

```
'siteUrl' => [
    'english' => 'https://www.mysite.com/',
    'japanese' => 'https://www. myjapanesesite.com/',
],
```

See documentation at: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#siteurl

Comment: Great!! Thanks for the answer. 
Now it is working fine if I go to myjapanesesite.com/home it takes me to the landing page. 
If i just go to myjapanesesite.com/ it takes me to the English site though..